# All Source Engine Games Crash a Few Minutes into Gameplay

Tags: games, steam, intel

I'm a pretty big fan of Linux, so I've been trying to make a full switch. Recently, though, I've hit a bit of a snag with running some of my games. I play most of my games through Steam, and most of them work fine. However, all games that were made in Valve's Source Engine (Portal 2, Team Fortress 2, GMod) will run for about 5-10 minutes before crashing to desktop. Launching the games from the console reveals they end with a nice old segmentation fault.

I run UbuntuMATE 16.04 x64 edition. Here are my computer's "specs" if you wish to have them:

Lenovo Yoga Laptop

256GB SSD (Where Ubuntu is)

1TB HDD (Where the games are)

2.5 GHz Intel Processor

Intel Video Card

8GB RAM

I've tried reinstalling mesa and installing the 32-bit packages for mesa and OpenGL. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry dude got you covered. For some stupid reason, Source Engine games will crash UNLESS they are on the default Steam download storage, since you have other storage, I willing to bet this is the problem. Simply go to Settings and go to Downloads. Go to Steam Library Folders and click your storage when you see it. There should be a prompt to change it to default. Now, you should be able to play your games without them crashing as much. (They might crash if your computer is overloaded.)